# How can I deal with amazon gateway prepending all url paths with /dev?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, fastapi, uvicorn

I have a FastAPI app where I have mounted a directory for static files like:

```
api.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory=os.path.join(this_directory, "static")))
```

When I deploy my FastAPI app to AWS, the API-gateway stage is called `dev` so all URL paths start with a `/dev` so in my HTML files, links like:

```
<script src="/static/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

Now no longer point to the correct location, instead, they need to point to

```
<script src="/dev/static/js/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```

I can go through and change all the links to start with `/dev` but then when I want to make a production stage, the links will now start at `/prod`.

How can I set up Mangum/Uvicorn to deal with a different start path to the URL?

For reference, I set up my api-gateway using ANY to `/{proxy+}` resource of a lambda function with a FastAPI app.

Comment: You need to provide a custom domain name mapping for the api gateway: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Comment: @luk2302 I'm new to AWS. How do the different stages (i.e. dev, production) work when you setup a domain name?

Comment: That is not answerable in such a general manner. I would not have dev and prod in same AWS account to begin with. But if you have them you can maybe have two domain name mappings, one for dev, one for prod and they have different domain name mappings, maybe api.yourdomain.com and dev.api.yourdomain.com

Comment: @luk2302 Thanks. I will try that